# Proof of Poincare inequality -Sufficient proof

Tags: calculus, probability, analysis

I was reading the proof of the Gaussian Poincare inequality
$$\text{Var}(f(X)) \leq \mathbb E[f'(X)^2]$$
Where $X$ is the standard normal random variable and $f$ is a continuously differentiable function. The proof states that it is sufficient to prove the inequality for functions that have compact support and is twice continuously differentiable. I don't see why this is a sufficient condition. I am guessing this is because every differentiable function can be approximated in some way by twice continuously differentiable functions with compact support. Can anyone please help?

Comment: the space of test functions is dense in all $L_p$ spaces for $p\neq \infty $

Comment: By test functions do you mean twice continuously differentiable functions with compact support?

Comment: no, I mean test functions. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_of_test_functions_and_distributions)